# <meta charset="utf-8"> still needed today?

Tags: html, meta-tags

I look at the bootstrap4 introduction and see this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/

Is `<meta charset="utf-8">` still needed today?

I only support browsers with a market share greater than 2%.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the charset meta tag required with HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669352/is-the-charset-meta-tag-required-with-html5)

Answer (score 0):

it's not necessary but it doesn't hurt to add an single line to your code.