# How to set emoji unicode dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, unicode, utf-8

This is what my html code looks like:

```
<html>
<style>
    body {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <span id="tiger" style='font-size:100px;'>&#128161;</span>
    <button id="btn">SET TIGER</button>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            document.getElementById('tiger').innerText = `&#129409;`;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work and shows just `&#129409;` instead of emoji when click button. Why is that, how can I set emoji dynamically?

Comment: _“Why is that”_ - because you are not aware of the difference between `innerText` and `innerHTML` …? `&#129409;` only _means_ “numeric HTML character reference” in an HTML context. In a text context, it is just that - _text_.

Answer (score 7):

**HTML Escapes**

HTML escapes like "&#128161;" are decoded by the HTML parser when the source document is being parsed.

To set the content of a text node, use a JavaScript string  - which  technically is encoded in UTF-16.

**JavaScript Strings**

If you knew the hexadecimal representation of the character in UTF-16 you  *could* set text node content using an escaped string like

```
element.textContent = "\ud83d\udca1"; // not recommended.
```

If you knew the Unicode value in hex or decimal you could use the static String `fromCodePoint` method:

```
 element.textContent = String.fromCodePoint( 0x1f4a1) // or
 element.textContent = String.fromCodePoint( 128161 )
```

Another choice is to escape a 6 hex character code using a unicode escape with curly braces in JavaScript:

```
 element.textContent = '\u{01f4a1}'; // still not recommended
```

However, the method I would recommend is to encode the HTML file in UTF-8 when saving and set the text content with a standard string value in code:

```
 element.textContent = ''
```

Limited code editor support for Unicode fonts makes this a bit difficult, of course.

---

**Specifying Character Encoding**

As mentioned in comment, the character encoding used in HTML files can be specified at the top of the head section before the use of non-ASCII characters. Placing the [meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attributes)

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
```

immediately after the opening `<html>` tag will achieve this.

While the default encoding in HTML5 is 'utf-8', browsers on older mobile devices may still require use of the meta tag above. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52351400/5217142) from three years ago for more details.

Comment: For people like me who didn't know, you can change the HTML file to UTF-8 encoding by adding this `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` inside the `<head>` tag. Then setting the innerText to the standard string value as @traktor said.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<style>
    body {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <span id="tiger" style='font-size:100px;'>&#128161;</span>
    <button id="btn">SET TIGER</button>

    <script>
    var code = '129409';
         //
        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            document.getElementById('tiger').innerText = String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(code));;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly check below, Hope your query is resolved.

```
<html>
<style>
    body {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <span id="tiger" style='font-size:100px;'>&#128161;</span>
    <button id="btn">SET TIGER</button>

    <script>
    var code = '129409';
         //
        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            document.getElementById('tiger').innerText = String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(code));;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```