# Why is it required to specify character encoding, given that UTF-8 is the only valid encoding?

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8, language-lawyer

From the [HTML Standard § 4.2.5.4 Specifying the document's character encoding](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#character-encoding-declaration):

> The Encoding standard requires use of the UTF-8 character encoding and requires use of the "utf-8" encoding label to identify it. Those requirements necessitate that the document's character encoding declaration, if it exists, specifies an encoding label using an ASCII case-insensitive match for "utf-8". Regardless of whether a character encoding declaration is present or not, the actual character encoding used to encode the document must be UTF-8.
>
> (…)
>
> If an HTML document does not start with a BOM, and its encoding is not explicitly given by Content-Type metadata, and the document is not an iframe srcdoc document, then the encoding must be specified using a meta element with a charset attribute or a meta element with an http-equiv attribute in the Encoding declaration state.
>
> Note. A character encoding declaration is required (either in the Content-Type metadata or explicitly in the file) even when all characters are in the ASCII range, because a character encoding is needed to process non-ASCII characters entered by the user in forms, in URLs generated by scripts, and so forth.

So my understanding is that:

- There is only one allowed encoding, namely UTF-8.
- Nonetheless the encoding must still be explicitly specified.

Why?

Isn't this redundant to specify the encoding if the encoding must always be UTF-8?

Provided that the document specifies it is written in HTML 5 (eg if it declares `<!DOCTYPE html>` as opposed to, say, something like `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` it seems to me that character encoding could be optional with user agents defaulting to UTF-8 if not specified?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: (1) [Why it's necessary to specify the character encoding in an HTML5 document if the default character encoding for HTML5 is UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52351400/2985643) and/or (2) [Does HTML5 specify a default character encoding for HTML documents if no character encoding is supplied?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12406066/2985643)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why it's necessary to specify the character encoding in an HTML5 document if the default character encoding for HTML5 is UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351400/why-its-necessary-to-specify-the-character-encoding-in-an-html5-document-if-the)