# Python, output º symbol in utf-8 within HTTP while.write

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

As stated, trying to output the degree symbol to a HTTP server. When I do this the output is `Â°` with the unwanted A character

The current code I am using to output this is:

```
self.wfile.write(bytes(("<br>Average Temperature in last 24 hours = "+str(round(totalTempPast/pastCount,2))+" \N{DEGREE SIGN}C"),"utf-8"))
```

Which gives the result `Average Temperature in last 24 hours = 16.04 Â°C`

I have tried using `chr(223)` and `\xb0` (within a string) too which has the same result.

How would I go about fixing this?

Thanks

Comment: Rather than trying to force HTML to accept weird characters, you might be better off using the html escape, which is `&deg;` (five characters total).

Comment: It seems you are writing the file correctly. So I assume the problem is that the webpage is read as Latin-1 (which it is a problem, now all web should use UTF-8, but for old-compatibility, so old pages)

Answer (score 2):

In UTF-8, the degree sign ([Unicode U+00B0](https://symbl.cc/en/00B0/)) is encoded as `C2 B0`. The "Â" letter that got printed is the [Unicode U+00C2](https://symbl.cc/en/00C2/) character. It looks like Python prints the UTF-8 bytes as desired, but the browser did not interpret it correctly.

When you don't specify what encoding to use in an HTML document, the browser will take the liberty to [guess/auto-detect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75471128/19620878) one and use it. In your case, they took the wrong guess (e.g. guessing it as Latin-1) and so the weird character got displayed.

There are some alternative solutions:

1. As pointed out by @Tom Karzes in the comment, use the HTML escapes `&deg;` or `&#xB0;`
2. [Specify the encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12406142/19620878) of your HTML document. It is a best practice to always do this. There are several different ways to do it, here are some for summary:

a. The meta charset tag

Add the following snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    ...
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

b. `Content-Type` HTTP header

Add the following HTTP header to your HTTP response:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Once the encoding is specified, the same python code should be interpreted correctly by the browser and the undesired character wouldn't be displayed.